# Unable to communicate with bluetooth devices on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat, android-bluetooth

Is there a return code for "Unable to communicate with ..." bluetooth devices that I can catch somehow to handle these occasions?

I am building a Bluetooth handling activity to pair/unpair, but in some occasions if the discoverable device is unreachable I get this message(Toast) from the system(Android) and I want to be able to handle this somehow.

Comment: Quite surprised to get this toast also. For me, it seems likely to happen when the peripheral device is not bonded and when android is requesting bonding. Will do some test on it.